# Is there a way to change stroke color in html canvas using css

Tags: javascript, html, css, electronic-signature, signaturepad

I have in my page a signature pad where the user can make an electronic signature. I am using js librairy SignaturePad(https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad).

My signature pad background color is black so I have set my stroke color to white. After saving the signature in my DB you have the option to print a report with the signature in it but this time the background is white.

My problem is that since the user is signing in white when you try to print the report, you can't see the signature since it's white on white.

Does anybody have an idea on how i could like change the signature color to white using css or other method to keep the default color(black) when im saving the signature in my DB ?

Comment: You can’t change a stroke Color using CSS but you could change a Color using Javascript. How are you storing the signatures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `penColor` is saved on the points/url when you save the signature.

You can use `getData()` to get all the points, then use `forEach()` to loop over them and change the `penColor` accordingly.

```js
const data = signaturePad.toData();
data.forEach(p => p.penColor = 'black')
```

The `backgroundColor` can be changed on run-time as desired

```
signaturePad.backgroundColor = 'white'
```

---

Demo:

1. Create with `backgroundColor: 'black'` and `penColor: 'white'`
2. Press the button
3. `backgroundColor` is set to `white`
4. Change the `penColor` as described above
5. Re-draw using `fromData`

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('signature-pad');

var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas, { backgroundColor: 'black', penColor: 'white' });

document.getElementById('save-png').addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (signaturePad.isEmpty()) {
      return alert("Please provide a signature first.");
    }

    const data = signaturePad.toData();
    data.forEach(p => p.penColor = 'black')
    signaturePad.backgroundColor = 'white'

    signaturePad.fromData(data, { clear: true });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://szimek.github.io/signature_pad/js/signature_pad.umd.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <canvas id="signature-pad" class="signature-pad" width=400 height=200></canvas>
</div>

<button id="save-png">Press to re-draw</button>
```